# javac.exe codigo 3

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me sale ese error al correr el proyecto Android de Xamarin Forms, espero me puedan ayudar... Ya intenté limpiar y recompilar, crear otro proyecto, habilitar multidex... Me sale ese error corriendo en máquina virtual como en dispositivo físico.

Comment: Es importante que los errores esten como texto y no como imagenes. Ademas, necesitamos un poco mas de información para saber que puede estar pasando (tu código, o que paso antes de que sucediera este error)

Comment: Pues es un proyecto en blanco de XamarinForms, no le agregué ni una línea de código, lo corría para probarlo y pues así me resultó...

Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error "javac.exe" salió con el código 3. Prueba.Android